# How to change the color of a textual cue when sending an EM_SETCUEBANNER Message?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

When you send an [EM_SETCUEBANNER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761639(VS.85).aspx) message, you get a grey textual cue in your edit control. How do you change the color of the textual cue in Win32/C ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit controls do not support custom cue banner colors.  You will have to subclass the Edit control and custom-draw it manually to get that kind of effect.